# The changes I make in javascript are not displayed on the site and I don't know what the problem is

Tags: javascript, php

here code in VS. This is a js file which make changes in PHP site.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
    } );

    function replaceClass(id, oldClass, newClass) {
        var elem = $(`#${id}`);
        if (elem.hasClass(oldClass)) {
            elem.removeClass(oldClass);
        }
        elem.addClass(newClass);
    }
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#darkmode").click(function() {
            replaceClass("garden", "light", "dark");
        });
     
        $("#lightmode").click(function() {
            replaceClass("garden", "dark", "light");
        });
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
        const deadline = new Date(2024, 11, 26);
        let timerId = null;
        function declensionNum(num, words) {
          return words[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(num % 10 < 5) ? num % 10 : 5]];
        }
        function countdownTimer() {
          const diff = deadline - new Date();
          if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
          }
          const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
          const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
          const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
          const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
          $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
          $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
          $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
          $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
          $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'днів']);
          $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['година', 'години', 'годин']);
          $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['хвилина', 'хвилини', 'хвилин']);
          $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунди', 'секунд']);
        }
        const $days = document.querySelector('.timer__days');
        const $hours = document.querySelector('.timer__hours');
        const $minutes = document.querySelector('.timer__minutes');
        const $seconds = document.querySelector('.timer__seconds');
        countdownTimer();
        timerId = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
      });



// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

and here code in site.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
    } );

    function replaceClass(id, oldClass, newClass) {
        var elem = $(`#${id}`);
        if (elem.hasClass(oldClass)) {
            elem.removeClass(oldClass);
        }
        elem.addClass(newClass);
    }
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#darkmode").click(function() {
            replaceClass("garden", "light", "dark");
        });
     
        $("#lightmode").click(function() {
            replaceClass("garden", "dark", "light");
        });
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
        const deadline = new Date(2024, 11, 26);
        let timerId = null;
        function declensionNum(num, words) {
          return words[(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2][(num % 10 < 5) ? num % 10 : 5]];
        }
        function countdownTimer() {
          const diff = deadline - new Date();
          if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
          }
          const days = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) : 0;
          const hours = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 : 0;
          const minutes = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60) % 60 : 0;
          const seconds = diff > 0 ? Math.floor(diff / 1000) % 60 : 0;
          $days.textContent = days < 10 ? '0' + days : days;
          $hours.textContent = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
          $minutes.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
          $seconds.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
          $days.dataset.title = declensionNum(days, ['день', 'дня', 'днів']);
          $hours.dataset.title = declensionNum(hours, ['година', 'години', 'годин']);
          $minutes.dataset.title = declensionNum(minutes, ['хвилина', 'хвилини', 'хвилин']);
          $seconds.dataset.title = declensionNum(seconds, ['секунда', 'секунди', 'секунд']);
        }
        const $days = document.querySelector('.timer__days');
        const $hours = document.querySelector('.timer__hours');
        const $minutes = document.querySelector('.timer__minutes');
        const $seconds = document.querySelector('.timer__seconds');
        countdownTimer();
        timerId = setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000);
      });
```

mayde anybody can help me, i will be so thanksfull

i tried changed my site from PHP to HTML (I write site on PHP) and this didnt help me. maybe you have any idea.

Actually, i think this is because i have wrong version of something but maybe my code wrong.

Comment: We need more context. What do you mean by "PHP site" ? Where is it hosted ? Which version of php do you use ?  What do you mean by "make changes" ? What do you mean by "changed my site from PHP to HTML" ?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I'm new and just learning. The previous problem is solved. Only if you know, then tell me why the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Tell me what you need to reset for this.

Comment: Right after this error you should have the name the JS file where the error occurs and the number of the file. If you give me this and the content of the file I could have a look.
But I advice you ti open a new thread for a new problem.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that the javascript file was loaded before the jquery file. Thank you for the time you spent on me. You are a very good person.

Comment: No problem, have a good day and enjoy coding :)